# Validation button for login fragment in the activity

Tags: android, fragment

I have an activity with a bar and a Framelayout.
This is how the bar is :
[image: Activity bar]

This is my fragment (at the bottom of the Activity bar) :
[image: fragment]

I would like to validate the connection when the user click on the validation (blue) button on the Activity.

How can I do that ?

Comment: what kind of validation you need? connection means data connectivity or you need to validate the user inputs?

Comment: Are you trying to implement a clickListener for the blue tick on the ActionBar? Also, in terms of validation - what are you validating, or do you simply send the login details of the user to your server when the use clicks the blue button?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could listen for the onCLick action, as the following shows:

```
blueButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        //do your validation stuff
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, your_next_activity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
   }
 });
```

In before, don't forget to instantiate the button with something like:

```
    private Button blueButton;
        blueButton= (Button)rootView.findViewById(R.id.your_button_id);
```

Comment: With that it's working : getActivity().findViewById(R.id.your_button_id);